# Image in datalist tag

Tags: html, image, html-datalist

Is it possible to add an image into a datalist option? I'm building a search for my users where I want the avatar to show up along with the name and bio in the datalist sort of like on Twitter or Facebook. The `$avatar` variable has the link or src to the image.

Also is there an alternative to datalist because datalist is not supported in Safari?

```
<form action='results.php'>
   <input list="Search" name="browser" placeholder="Search">
      <datalist id="Search">
    <?php
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profile where iduser!=$iduser ORDER BY username ");
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){                  
     $username = $row['username'];
     $bio = $row['bio'];
     $avatar = $row['avatar'];        
          echo "<option width='50px'value='$username'>/*Image and bio in here?*/</option>";
       }
       ?>
      </datalist>
   <input type=submit value=SEARCH />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because the predefined options are shown (by supporting browsers) as a list consisting of only the text content of the `option` elements. While the `datalist` element’s content model allows any phrasing content, including images, that content is ignore by browsers that support the element; it is meant to act only as fallback content (to be displayed by browsers that ignore `datalist` markup and `option` elements when they don’t appear inside a `select` element).

What comes closest to having icons associated with the options is to use a font that contains the icons as glyphs for Private Use code points such as E+0000 and insert such code points into `option` contents, e.g. `<option>&#xe000; Foo Bar</option>`. When that font is used as a downloadable font via `@font-face` works technically well (so-called icon fonts use similar techniques), it is clumsy, limited (only monochrome icons), and theoretically wrong (Private Use code points should not be used in public information interchange).

Regarding other approaches, consider using a set of checkboxes or radio buttons with associated labels that may well contain images, too. Since this limits the choices to the given alternatives, you need to add a free text input field to allow any other alternative to be specified.

Comment: Well that sucks... :( I wonder what Twitter or Facebook use then.

Comment: @TimTom, they use other technologies, and you can see them to some extent by looking at their source code. Using scripting, you can create a pile of `div` elements containing images and names so that they are clickable.